# Pitot and static port placement - How to choose the ideal location

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pressure, sensors, aerodynamics, aircraft-design

Forgive the this topic placement as it might be similar to other older ones (Although I a bit sure that the main contents might be different than other older ones).
In the upcoming days I will have a very important interview to a position I am interested as it is involved around a passion of mine. I would like to gain some insights in the following topics (any research paper, final thesis, or other explanatory material is more than welcome).

1. Pitot and static sensors placement. How do we choose the most ideal
   position on an aircraft's structure to place these sensors? What do we
   need to take into consideration apart from document standards?
2. Definition of air data related measurement points and routing of
   pressure tubes involved. Calibration of air data systems.

Any help is much appreciated,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does the pressure distribution change over the fuselage? Do you think they do wind tunnel testing and cfd to find out? Or it’s just WAG?

Comment: No WAG will take place. CFD and physical testing could take place as well. I can imagine that in a possible CFD simulation after defining the simulated conditions such as airflow velocity and turbulence pressure distribution over the structure can be obtained.

Comment: One question of mine though is how does someone assess the information over the whole flight envelope. Obtaining multiple diagram from multiple "operational conditions" someone would expect the pressure distribution to be extremely different from case to case (or at least this is an assumption of mine). How then this location is estimated? What are the characteristics of the spot that we need to install the sensors? Also consider the fact that we are talking for a VTOL aircraft, thus the downwash of the rotors can drastically affect the measurements.